# Infinispan , How to assure read write lock on a key/cache

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, jboss-cache

We are planning to use `Infinispan` in client server mode. The architecture has many `clients (client 1, client 2 and so on )` and a distributed `infinispan` network.

We need to update the data in the cache periodically, say every`5 hours` . All clients could be able to update the data. If one of them (say `client 1`) is updating we need to prevent others doing the same job. Once the updating is complete all clients wait another 5 hour and, any of them will do the the updating again.

How to achieve this in `infinispan 6`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the clients are on different machines (you run Infinispan as server(s)), you should use HotRod clients to access the cache. There, see the `getVersioned` and `replaceWithVersion` methods on 
[`RemoteCache`](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/RemoteCache.html).

Comment: Ah, I haven't noticed that you know about these operations (according to your previous question).

Comment: this question I have asked before I get information about the versioned Api. But as discussed in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522203/infinispan-the-versioned-operation-returning-incorrect-results  I have share the log file which you asked. Can u please check the issue?

Comment: I've updated the other answer. Then, please mark this answer as correct.