# Infinispan, the versioned operation returning incorrect results

Tags: java, caching, jboss, infinispan

We are planning to use Infinispan in client server mode. The architecture has many clients (client 1, client 2 and so on ) and a distributed infinispan network.

We need to update the data in the cache periodically, say every5 hours . All clients could be able to update the data. If one of them (say client 1) is updating we need to prevent others doing the same job. Once the updating is complete all clients wait another 5 hour and, any of them will do the the updating again.

Infinispan providing a versioned operation for this, But during the testing this methord is giving invalid result.

```
String key="test";
RemoteCacheManager cacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager();
RemoteCache<String, Object> remoteCache = cacheManager.getCache("MyCache");
remoteCache.put(key, new Object());
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("version Before:" + remoteCache.getVersioned(key).getVersion());
        System.out.println("version to put:"+(i));
        System.out.println(remoteCache.replaceWithVersion(key, new Object(),i));
        System.out.println("version after:" + remoteCache.getVersioned(key).getVersion());
        System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

This is giving correct result like,

```
version Before:1
version to put:1
true
version after:2
---------------------
version Before:2
version to put:2
true
version after:3
---------------------
version Before:3
version to put:3
true
version after:4
---------------------
```

But once I add a new different key to the same cache the version to the old key is giving incorrectly

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    remoteCache.put("Hello", new Object());
    System.out.println("version Before:" + remoteCache.getVersioned(key).getVersion());
    System.out.println("version to put:"+(i));
    System.out.println(remoteCache.replaceWithVersion(key, new Object(),i));
    System.out.println("version after:" + remoteCache.getVersioned(key).getVersion());
    System.out.println("---------------------");
```

}

```
version Before:1
version to put:1
true
version after:3
---------------------
version Before:3
version to put:2
false
version after:3
---------------------
version Before:3
version to put:3
true
version after:6
---------------------
version Before:6
version to put:4
false
version after:6
---------------------
```

Looks like version is changing irrespective of the key but for cache. Because while inserting a different key to cache the version of existing also changes.

**Update:- This was not a bug, it is the expected behavior, see the answer and its discussion.**

Comment: No, the version is associated with the key. There's probably something wrong with the test. Please, add the clear operation before the test execution to make sure that the cache is empty before the test.

Comment: If you still think that there's a problem, enable TRACE logging in server on org.infinispan package and link the log here.

Comment: @Flavius I have enabled the trace but it is too much, can I paste it here

Comment: Sure, trace logs are verbose. Zip it and upload to Dropbox and post just the link.

Comment: @Flavius please find the test classes and logs here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107000372/Test.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When you write a new entry into the cache, it gets a new version. New versions are obtained from atomic counter which makes sure that always some new version is generated. You cannot know this new version unless you call the getWithVersion.

Comment: If you found some information in documentation that would state otherwise, please send a link for that, it will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. It means Infinispan is maintaining a single atomic variable for the whole cache right rather than for separate keys?

Comment: No, each entry (key + value) has one number (long), that's the current version. However, when a the entry is overwritten, it gets a new version set to next number retrieved from atomic counter which is only one for whole cache.